# What are the advantages of using SMS Gateway for sending/receiving text messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms

I'm using a Rails application and would like to send/receive text messages through my application. Two solutions I looked at is using SMS Gateway and using a cell phone paired with Bluetooth with my Mac and I have ultraSMS program running that sends SMSs through the phone. The second option is definitely a lot cheaper as SMS gateways charges quite a bit for a dedicated number. The disadvantages of the second option as far as I know are 1. Reliability: phone and computer has to be on and paired at all time 2. Scalability

Is there other major advantages to SMS gateways worth paying for? Are there other alternatives?

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is not so critical you can use email to sms. SO has some questions about email to sms. You can search them.

I would prefer an SMS gateway than using a personal mobile phone. You cannot send BULK sms using a mobile phone at the same time. Mobile phones send one sms at a time so its time consuming.

In India SMS gateways are cheaper (for bulk purchases) than mobile phones. You can choose a Sender ID which can contain alphabets and numbers. This is another advantage of bulk sms as it will look more professional.

The Sender ID facility is not available when you send sms using a mobiole phone. Name can be displayed only if the receiver has your number stored.

Anoter advantage is reports. Gateways usually have reports. You can generate customised report. Think about option for delivery report when you send sms through phone ;-)

Comment: Thanks. The issue with Email SMS is that some carriers in Canada (when I live and need to implement system) sometimes send msg stating that you received an email msg "reply to view message" which is inconvenient.
I will do more research for SMS gateways coz the ones here are quite pricey and some required few months or so commitment to give dedicated number

Answer (score 1):

At least here in Norway, SMS Gateways offer short (4 digit) numbers for incoming messages. Customers will begin messages with a code word, which will make the gateway route the message to your application. You indicate that you want a dedicated number, in which case this point is probably mute.

SMS gateway providers can often provide payment services for easy payment over the phone bill.

I guess SMS gateways usually will provide logging and statistics.

Answer (score 1):

- International pricing is certainly something to consider if you could be sending messages overseas.
- Throughput. Third parties can push through thousands of messages a second. Your phone cannot.
- Identification. When you send an SMS, it's your number attached to the message. Third parties can mask the number as a short one.
- Support for high-volume commercial texting. If you're using a regular tariff contract, you might find it is explicitly against the contract terms to send the messages you are. If that's the case and they find out, they're more than within their rights to leave you high-and-dry.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you should go for SMS Gateway solution. This will be proven as better ROI model on long term.

Secondly you need not buy a dedicated incoming number with gateway, you can just rent a KEYWORD on the Gateway number. All your customers will send their SMS requests to Gateway's dedicated number and all Messages starting with your hired keyword will be forwarded/routed to your Web-Application URL which receives the incoming messages.

Gateways also provide the services like auto-response which gives you 0 cost for outgoing message. The page which receives the incoming message from the Gateway will process the incoming message using the business rules and will respond with a text response within 160 characters which will then be received by the gateway and sent back to the requesting customer's mobile number. This is mainly a short-code model.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a good point I will do more research on renting keywords

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, integrating a cell phone with your software looks like a very strange solution. So, I'll describe the advantages of using an API for sending an sms with examples of [our API](https://developer.wavecell.com):

**It's easier**. As easy as signing up and sending a HTTP request:

```
curl -X "POST" https://api.wavecell.com/sms/v1/amazing_hq/single \
    -u amazing:1234512345 \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d $'{ "source": "AmazingDev", "destination": "+6512345678", "text": "Hello, World!" }'
```

Here's the [complete and very detailed tutorial](https://developer.wavecell.com/v1/tutorials/api-send-sms-single).

**It's more reliable and stable.** Achieving stable service is hard. If you want a high uptime, you need to develop a distrubuted system with monitoring and high-class operations team. If you need high delivery rate (do not lose your messages) you need constantly measure mobile carriers and SMS aggegators indicators.

**It's scalable**. It is possible to grow up to millions of SMS per day with the same stable quality which is not achieved with homemade cell phone solutions.

**It's global**. If you're sending, for example, from a Canada to a Singapore phone number, your carrier will bill this message with his roaming tariffs which are not the same as his local ones. Usually they're much more expensive than global gateways can offer for same delivery. You can check out [our prices](https://wavecell.com/messaging/) and compare.

**More features**. As @Shoban mentioned, these are: SenderIds and delivery reports. You might also need rich dashboard with analytics and monitoring. You can choose one of avaible protocols (HTTP, SMPP). Also we have bulk sms, sms scheduling, mobile verification API, ...