# alert to back office personnel on client side triggering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a ruby on rails project. it is a portal. I have a situation as follows:

the user browses around. Suddenly he gets a doubt.

I want to keep a small text box and a button that says "call me".

To clarify the doubt the user can enter his phone number in the "call me" box.

now the back office personnel should get an alert or a notification about this.

I tried implementing **juggernaut**, but became a nightmare since the site is in a shared host and i couldn't configure the port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. An ugly solution, with **pooling**:

Why not make a page that autorefreshes every 1 sec (for the backoffice staff) that just pools the table with customer requests for new data? So, one controller that stores that phone request (the telefone number, etc) and one admin controller that displays unread phone requests from the DB.

It is simple to implement, does not consume too many resources.

b. if you really want something that should '**ring**', you can integrate a **SMS gateway** and send a message to a backoffice phone number.

[SO thread about SMS GW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914847/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-sms-gateway-for-sending-receiving-text-messages)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just sending an email to the backoffice?

Comment: it appears to be the easiest way out..:) but i want a way that gets the staff's attention almost immediately.

Comment: It depends off course how the backoffice is organised. But most of the time a backoffice is checking the email on a regular base and have a sort of notification set for new email.

It is the easiest way out but in my opinion I think the best way to go, but again it entirely depends on the setup/workflow of the backoffice.

I'm curious what other people come up with...